# Power Rail swings on a Digital MCU

Tags: microcontroller, batteries

The acceptable power supply to several MCU's is quite wide. For example, TI CC2640R2F is 1.8V to 3.8V.
If powered directly from an LiSOCl2 battery, the input voltage would vary quite a bit depending on current draw.

If the supply voltage stays above the minimum limit, would the digital circuitry and firmware execute fine, or would there be potential for glitches when the input swings?
How would someone calculate the needed capacitance to remove glitches if there are any?

Comment: if well bypassed, should work just fine. The voltage will be constant at any specific moment, it goes down over long time, so nothing wrong with that, but make sure the rest of the circuit will behave as intended

Comment: You may not be able to run at all speeds at all voltages.

Comment: That particular chip has several power supply options including internal DC-DC and LDO, which were you thinking of? (Fig 7-2).

Comment: @Ilya Your answer makes the most sense to me, but would the datasheet recommended bypass capacitors be enough to make the voltage 'momentarily constant'?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Whichever option would allow for biggest input range. Would either option make for lower capacitance requirements?

Comment: @josephbarrymore I would put two bypass capacitors. 0.1uF and 10uF. One just to remove most noise, another as a little energy tank (and lower frequency noise too). Smaller cap closer to the pin. But yes, bypass cap is always a good idea. And yes, the frequency comment of DKNguyen is also correct, so you should run, well, definitely not at max frequency, datasheet of mcu will tell yoo more, it has Vdd vs Freq. tables/curves

Answer (score 0):

This is not about calculation as it is common off-the-shelf standards. For CPU / MCU voltage 3.3 volts is very common and at the upper end of what the TI CC2640R2F is rated for. Yes it can work at 1.8 volts but with limited maximum speed, while 3.3 volts should allow for maximum clock speed.

Capacitors are inserted because ALL electronic devices can be noisy, with the outputs causing current spikes at the power pins. Normally each power/ground pair has a local 100 nF capacitor and close by is a 4.7 uF capacitor. Common for the board would be a large 100 uF capacitor to act as a current reservoir.

If a local voltage regulator is used it also must have bypass capacitors on the input and output pins. Normally manufactures show some simple build examples for CPU's/MCU's and regulators to show power/ground layout and capacitor locations.

A well regulated supply with adequate bypass capacitors should not even have noticeable noise much less voltage swings over 50 mV from the stated voltage of the regulator.

Comment: What if there are large voltage swings due to an unregulated supply (LiSOCl2 battery)? How would one determine 'adequate' bypass capacitance?

Comment: @josephbarrymore Capacitors are for current surges that cause brief voltage dips. Even 2,200 uF is limited. Capacitors are NOT voltage regulators. You must have voltage regulators or some ICs can be damaged.